# Создал собственный класс обработки исключений, вопрос в том, как сделать radirect на страницу ошибки?

Tags: asp.net

```
public class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware> _logger;
    public ExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogCustomErrorPage(LogLevel.Error, (int)LoggingEventType.Log, string.Empty, exception, (t, e) => EventMessageBuilder.UserPageFormatter());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

В блок `catch` вместо `throw` добавьте следующий код:

```
context.Response.Redirect("https://google.com/");
```

Где передадите ссылку на свою страницу ошибки